# how assign "NA" value into new column in python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am not able to assign NA values to dataframe and while exporting to_csv file,its shows empty. please suggest.

[image]

Looking out put of Data_1 is :

[image]

```
for i in range(1, length):
    Nnw_ = np.array(data_1.iloc[0:(data_1.iloc[0:, i]).count(),[i]])
    rep = np.array(data_2.iloc[0:( data_2.iloc[0:, i]).count(),[i + 1]])
    data_1.replace(Nnw, rep, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please show a code example that illustrates the problem you are asking about.

Comment: afaik, by default np.nan is converted to an empty string in excel. maybe consider `.fillna("NA")`?

Comment: What do you mean by `NA`? The string `"NA"`? What did you try for now? Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions on this site. In any case, have a look at the pandas function [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: @code-apprentice :

Code

for i in range(1, length):

Nnw_ = np.array(data_1.iloc[0:(data_1.iloc[0:, i]).count(),[i]])
rep = np.array(data_2.iloc[0:( data_2.iloc[0:, i]).count(),[i + 1]])
data_1.replace(Nnw, rep, inplace=True)

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than posting code in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you **read** a DataFrame from a *CSV* file, it may contain missing values
represented a.o. as *NA*. So the **source** file can contain e.g.:

```
data_1,data_2
red,Rose
white,NA
yelow,NA
orange,Orange
```

But *read_csv* converts such missing values to *np.nan*, which are printed
as **NaN** and both columns are of **object** type.

As of *Pandas* version *1.0* it is possible to convert such columns
to **string** type:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

Now, when you run `df.info()`, you will get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   data_1  4 non-null      string
 1   data_2  2 non-null      string
dtypes: string(2)
memory usage: 192.0 bytes
```

(compare with the result of `df.info()` just after *read_csv*,
where the type is *object*).

This DataFrame can be saved to a *CSV* file, running e.g.
`df.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False, na_rep='NA')` and the result will be:

```
data_1,data_2
red,Rose
white,NA
yelow,NA
orange,Orange
```

Note parameters:

- `index=False` - to omit the output of the index,
- `na_rep='NA'` - to provide a visible representation of *NA* values
  (the default representation is an **empty** string).

## Edit

If you want to **replace** individual cells with *NA*, run e.g.:

```
df.iloc[3,1] = np.nan
```

Don't worry that you used *np.nan*. *Pandas* is clever enough to convert
it into *NA*.

If you copy values from *data_2* to *data_1*, there is no problem.
Note that after *convert_dtypes* **both** columns area of *string* type,
so *NA* values can be copied also to *data_1*.

If you don't want the missing values saved as *NA*, just drop *na_rep*
parameter from *to_csv* and they will be save as (the default) empty strings.

Comment: Thank for replay,,Here I have to replace the values data_2 to data_1 and its not a two data_frame. Actually its a column name data_1, data_2,, while exporting the data should be same